# Content not showing in front end

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Using Typo3 6.2.19 with themes (theme engine), themes_gridelements, theme_bootstrap.

I choose default theme on front page. Then added text element in main column. But it's not showing in front end.

Comment: included `css_styled_content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the contents on the frontend of your site, make sure you included the `css_styled_content` to your template.

Goto `Template -> Edit the whole template record -> Include`. Here you have the possibility to include the `css_styled_content`.